# Why that sql request take so long time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I work on prestashop 1.6 with a mysql5.6 database which have more the 7Gb. The very big problem when i want see my orders on my prestashop it take between 40s and 2 minutes and sometime it stuck.

I mention we process more then 80.000 orders, and we have like 200.000 products. We have tried many optimisation like indexation and make maximum of subqueries.

We got better time but it still very very slow. I try execute that request directly on mysql but the time is very variable sometime i got 50s and sometime i got 200s, the diference is very big.

```
    /*Request prestashop*/
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.id_order ,invoice_number,address.id_country 
     AS id_country, total_paid_tax_incl,payment, a.date_add 
     AS date_add , a.id_currency, a.id_order 
     AS id_pdf, CONCAT(LEFT(c.firstname, 1), '. ', c.lastname) 
     AS customer, osl.name 
     AS osname, os.color, 
     IF((
      SELECT so.id_order 
       FROM ps_orders so 
       WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer AND so.id_order < a.id_order 
       LIMIT 1
      ) > 0, 0, 1) AS new, 

     country_lang.name 
     AS cname, 
     IF(a.valid, 1, 0) badge_success,a.total_products,a.reference 
     AS reference,

/*Override request pesonalized*/


(
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT pr.product_group SEPARATOR ", ") /*DISTINCT*/
    FROM ps_order_detail dod 
    LEFT JOIN ps_product pr ON (pr.id_product = dod.product_id) 
        WHERE dod.id_order = a.id_order LIMIT 1 
) AS product_group,


(
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(hdb.product_reference SEPARATOR ", ") 
    FROM ps_order_detail hdb 
    WHERE hdb.id_order = a.id_order
) AS sku,


(
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(rop.id_order_lengow SEPARATOR ", ") 
    FROM ps_lengow_orders rop 
    WHERE rop.id_order = a.id_order
) AS marketplace,

( 
SELECT name 
FROM ps_supplier 
WHERE id_supplier = ( 
                        SELECT id_supplier FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = ( 
                            SELECT product_id FROM ps_order_detail rypl 
                            WHERE rypl.id_order = a.id_order 
                            LIMIT 1 
                        ) 
                    ) 
) 
AS fournisseur,

lo.id_order_lengow,
IF(lo.marketplace IS NOT NULL, lo.marketplace, 'royalprice') AS marketplace_name,

( 
    SELECT SUM( 
        IF ( lo.marketplace IS NULL AND 4 IN 
            (
                SELECT ps.id_supplier 
                FROM ps_product_supplier ps 
                WHERE p.id_product=ps.id_product
                )
            AND (
                SELECT cpp.price 
                FROM ps_cdiscount_products_price cpp 
                WHERE cpp.sku=p.reference LIMIT 1
                ) IS NOT NULL, 
            ( 
                SELECT cpp.price 
                FROM ps_cdiscount_products_price cpp 
                WHERE cpp.sku=p.reference LIMIT 1 
                ), 
            p.wholesale_price 
            ) 
        ) 
    FROM ps_product p
    WHERE p.id_product IN (
                            SELECT od.product_id AS id_product 
                            FROM ps_order_detail od 
                            WHERE od.id_order = a.id_order 
                            ) 
) AS total_wolesale, 

(
    SELECT mrp.margin_value 
    FROM ps_margin_rp mrp 
    WHERE mrp.id_order=a.id_order 
    LIMIT 1 
) AS margin_rp_value , 

(
    SELECT mmax.margin_value 
    FROM ps_margin_max mmax 
    WHERE mmax.id_order=a.id_order 
    LIMIT 1 
) AS margin_max_value , 
address.postcode 
FROM ps_orders a 

LEFT JOIN ps_customer c ON (c.id_customer = a.id_customer) 
INNER JOIN ps_address address ON address.id_address = a.id_address_delivery 
INNER JOIN ps_country country ON address.id_country = country.id_country 
INNER JOIN ps_country_lang country_lang ON (country.id_country = country_lang.id_country AND country_lang.id_lang = 1) 
LEFT JOIN ps_order_state os ON (os.id_order_state = a.current_state) 
LEFT JOIN ps_order_state_lang osl ON (os.id_order_state = osl.id_order_state AND osl.id_lang = 1) 
LEFT JOIN ps_lengow_orders lo ON (lo.id_order = a.id_order) 
WHERE 1 AND lo.marketplace IN ("Amazon","Ebay_fr") 
ORDER BY a.id_order DESC LIMIT 0,300
```

I dont understand why it takes so long. How can I make it faster?

Note:: @RemcoK, i run explain and i got that
[EXPLAIN RUN ALL !INDEX PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbLMj.jpg)

Comment: check your request time, waiting (TTFB) and content download time

Comment: have you run EXPLAIN {sql here}? it will show you where you need to make improvements.

Comment: Can you show us all the indexes you made? Because you need to created indexes for every JOIN relation you use. I also see a lot of string searches, that is much slower then int searches. Like; replace ("Amazon", "Ebay_fr") with (1, 2)

Comment: Yes of course only thing where it say is Use OR or EXISTS insead IN but is not possible.

Comment: @RemcoK.  very good idea to remplace string with int

Comment: If you run EXPLAIN, SQL will tell you if it uses the indexes to get the result:

Comment: @RemcoK. i just run  EXPLAIN you can see the result i attach a photo at my question

Comment: @GacheAndrei . . . I would suggest starting with much simpler queries to see where the performance problem lies.  Your query is rather complicated.

Comment: Based on the response of the EXPLAIN you can see there are not much indexes used. You can also created combined indexes. So created indexes for every JOIN or WHERE you do

Comment: Which query is the slowest?